# Create integrated terminal in C# (Mono) application

Tags: c#, shell, terminal, mono, pty

I'm working on a project where I would like to add an integrated terminal just like modern IDE's have (cross-platform Windows/Linux/MacOS). I have tested most of the basics by simply using a `System.Diagnostics.Process`. I can run commands and use I/O redirection to interact with it. For example: I can run bash on ubuntu and call commands.

But where I'm getting stuck with my experiments is implementing something like `nano` or `vi(m)`. How exactly would that work? How do I send commands to the nano like `Ctrl+x` to exit? Also, when VIM is started in JetBrains Rider I also get these help indicators for the shortcuts etc. I suppose that's custom made.

Can I get this done with just c# or should I resort to native (c/c++) as the API? And how would that work exactly? I just need some API to interact with and I'll render the output in my c# application.

Thanks in advance,

Ruben

Comment: MonoDevelop has such a feature, but you might need to extract the necessary code from it.

Comment: So I found this: https://github.com/microsoft/vs-pty.net. Which I think does what I need it to do. I tried building it but I couldn't get it to work so I asked for help in an existing issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vs-pty.net/issues/16. I have some binaries now and I'll be trying to integrate this. 

To be continued :)